# Why this mutation GraphQL query does not pass data through?

Tags: java, graphql, spring-graphql

I have the Mutation below and I'd like to test it with the script below, but I don't know what is the problem with it.

I already checked the documentation, at least 10 tutorials and according to those it should work, but it doesn't:

- when remove the NonNull from the Mutation the code breaks at server side at validations with the same error, the passed object is null
- I also ensured that the `DocumentDto` class has a public zero args constructor
- the error is reproducable via GraphiQL too

Mutation

```gql
type Mutation {
    createDocument(documentInput: DocumentInput!): Document
}
```

Java test code:

```java
@Test
public void shouldCreateDocument_andReturnIt() {

    // Arrange

    // Act
    DocumentDto result = httpGraphQlTester.document("""
               mutation createDocument($documentInput: DocumentInput!) {
                 createDocument(documentInput: $documentInput) {
                   id
                   name
                   desc
                 }
               }
            """)
        .variable("id", 0L)
        .variable("name", "named")
        .variable("desc", "descd")
        .execute()
        .path("data")
        .entity(DocumentDto.class)
        .get();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Response has 1 unexpected error(s) of 1
> total. If expected, please filter them out: [{message=Variable
> 'documentInput' has an invalid value: Variable 'documentInput' has
> coerced Null value for NonNull type 'DocumentInput!',
> locations=[{line=1, column=28}],
> extensions={classification=ValidationError}}] Request: document='
> mutation createDocument($documentInput: DocumentInput!) {
> createDocument(documentInput: $documentInput) {
> id
> name
> desc
> }    } ', variables={id=0, name=named, desc=descd}
>
> at
> org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.DefaultGraphQlTester$DefaultRequest.lambda$assertDecorator$3(DefaultGraphQlTester.java:183)
> at
> org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.DefaultGraphQlTester$ResponseDelegate.verifyErrors(DefaultGraphQlTester.java:266)
> at
> org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.DefaultGraphQlTester$DefaultResponse.path(DefaultGraphQlTester.java:293)
> at
> com.encyclopediagalactica.document.e2e.CreateDocumentE2ETest.shouldCreateDocument_andReturnIt(CreateDocumentE2ETest.java:36)

Answer (score 0):

Your mutation wants a variable called `documentInput` but you are passing `id`, `name`, and `desc`

`id`, `name`, and `desc` are the expected fields in the *result* of the mutation, not inputs.

Look at your server's GraphQL schema to understand what the shape of `documentInput` is.